# Display WordPress post using bootstrap tabs and pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to display a list of posts with the bootstrap tab and pagination.
I have three tabs (Both, Blog, News). I am using next_posts_link and previous_posts_link for pagination. My bootstrap tab is working fine so is pagination. But when I try to go to another tab like the blog and try to paginate there the system is taking me to the first tab. Here is my full code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Both</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Blog</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">News</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
  <section class="vendor-section-2 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        
        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'paged' => $paged
                ) 
              );
              $page_amount = $the_query->max_num_pages; 
     
    
?>
        <div class="container pagination-count">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p>Page <span><?php echo $paged ?></span> of <span><?php echo $page_amount ?></span> </p>  
                </div>


            </div>

     
        </div>
<?php
    
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
?>                                                 

            <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.111" height="23.646" viewBox="0 0 24.111 23.646" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                                <path
                                    id="Path_84"
                                    data-name="Path 84"
                                    d="M9.544.241a3.061,3.061,0,0,1,3.348.642c1.4,1.427,4.322,1.638,5.638,2.976,1.49,1.518,1.358,4.151,2.856,5.584a7.9,7.9,0,0,1,2.163,8.913,7.942,7.942,0,0,1-3.789,4.323c-6.319,2.6-14.617-.268-18.3-5.889-1.8-2.745-2.12-6.848.122-9.133C3.947,5.245,5.608,1.887,9.544.241Z"
                                    fill="#f3943f"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Read More 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
                        
                    endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();  
                
                endif;?>
            <div class="next-prev-btn">
                <!-- then the pagination links -->
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
  <section class="vendor-section-2 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        
        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'category_name' => 'blog',
                  'paged' => $paged
                ) 
              );
              $page_amount = $the_query->max_num_pages; 
     
    
?>
        <div class="container pagination-count">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p>Page <span><?php echo $paged ?></span> of <span><?php echo $page_amount ?></span> </p>  
                </div>


            </div>

     
        </div>
<?php
    
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
?>                                                 

            <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.111" height="23.646" viewBox="0 0 24.111 23.646" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                                <path
                                    id="Path_84"
                                    data-name="Path 84"
                                    d="M9.544.241a3.061,3.061,0,0,1,3.348.642c1.4,1.427,4.322,1.638,5.638,2.976,1.49,1.518,1.358,4.151,2.856,5.584a7.9,7.9,0,0,1,2.163,8.913,7.942,7.942,0,0,1-3.789,4.323c-6.319,2.6-14.617-.268-18.3-5.889-1.8-2.745-2.12-6.848.122-9.133C3.947,5.245,5.608,1.887,9.544.241Z"
                                    fill="#f3943f"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Read More 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
                        
                    endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();  
                
                endif;?>
            <div class="next-prev-btn">
                <!-- then the pagination links -->
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
  <section class="vendor-section-2 mt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        
        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( 
                array( 
                  'posts_per_page' => 6, 
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'category_name' => 'news',
                  'paged' => $paged
                ) 
              );
              $page_amount = $the_query->max_num_pages; 
     
    
?>
        <div class="container pagination-count">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <p>Page <span><?php echo $paged ?></span> of <span><?php echo $page_amount ?></span> </p>  
                </div>


            </div>

     
        </div>
<?php
    
if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();
$post_id = get_the_ID(); 
?>                                                 

            <div class="col-md-4 mt-5">
                <div class="card">
                <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
                        <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="read-more" >
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24.111" height="23.646" viewBox="0 0 24.111 23.646" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: -5px;">
                                <path
                                    id="Path_84"
                                    data-name="Path 84"
                                    d="M9.544.241a3.061,3.061,0,0,1,3.348.642c1.4,1.427,4.322,1.638,5.638,2.976,1.49,1.518,1.358,4.151,2.856,5.584a7.9,7.9,0,0,1,2.163,8.913,7.942,7.942,0,0,1-3.789,4.323c-6.319,2.6-14.617-.268-18.3-5.889-1.8-2.745-2.12-6.848.122-9.133C3.947,5.245,5.608,1.887,9.544.241Z"
                                    fill="#f3943f"
                                />
                            </svg>
                            Read More 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php
                        
                    endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();  
                
                endif;?>
            <div class="next-prev-btn">
                <!-- then the pagination links -->
                <?php next_posts_link( 'Next &rarr;', $the_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous &larr; ' ); wp_reset_query();?>

            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

  </div>
</div>
```

Can you guys please me here?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using this script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }

});
```